# AngularJs + jQUery Mobile not working in Phonegap

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile, cordova, routes

I started my project on PhoneGap with angular js and jquery mobile. Somehow the routing is'nt working, I googled and came across a conflict between jquery mobile and angularjs [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6548).

This is the error which I am getting:

```
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122): TypeError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at Object.LocationHashbangUrl.$$parse (file:///android_asset/www/lib/angularjs/angular.js:9321:41)
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at file:///android_asset/www/lib/angularjs/angular.js:9878:21
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/angularjs/angular.js:12701:28)
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at Scope.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/lib/angularjs/angular.js:12513:31)
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at file:///android_asset/www/lib/angularjs/angular.js:9887:45
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at file:///android_asset/www/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4539:7
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/angularjs/angular.js:325:18)
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at fireUrlChange (file:///android_asset/www/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4538:5)
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at m.event.dispatch (file:///android_asset/www/lib/jquery.js:3:8436)
11-25 12:31:49.628: E/Web Console(7122):     at r.handle (file:///android_asset/www/lib/jquery.js:3:5139) at file:///android_asset/www/lib/angularjs/angular.js:10071
```

Is there any alternate work around to make this both work together?

I am using 1.2.25 angularjs and jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.

My routes:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'assets/login/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
    });
});
```

If I change my default route to:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'assets/login/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
    });
});
```

Then it works like charm.

Comment: There are many articles about disabling JQM routing when using backbone.js (and a sample in JQM demos). Maybe can you use the same principle for angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@QuickFix
Thanks I removed the JQM routing and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem resolved initially by introducing the otherwise

```
serviceApp.config(['$routeProvider',

 function($routeProvider){

   $routeProvider.
   when('/services',{
      templateUrl : 'partials/services.html',
      controller : 'servicesCtrl'

   }).
    when('/service/:id',{
       templateUrl : 'partials/service-details.html',
       controller : 'serviceDetailsCtrl'

    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/services'
    });


 }]);
```

But still faced the same problem in other cases, then after searching google, figure out that seems jquery mobile and angularjs is not compatible, but still required jquery mobile for some operation, so then downloaded the required modules of jquery mobile like mostly we require touch support, then used the module alone